# How do i load a text file from a listbox if the name is unkown in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

So sitting here trying to work this open basically I have two listboxs the 1st is a selection list and if you click on one of the options it pulls a list of files and places them in to listbox2.

Now I am trying to workout how to open the files I pulled in to the listbox if one is selected in to a richtextbox.

This is what I have so far, but the listbox 2is not working:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ListBox1.Text = "Custom" Then
        Dim folderInfo As New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\Users\A\Desktop\Project1\Project1\My Project\Responses\Custom")
        Dim arrFilesInFolder() As IO.FileInfo
        Dim fileInFolder As IO.FileInfo
        arrFilesInFolder = folderInfo.GetFiles("*.*")
        For Each fileInFolder In arrFilesInFolder
            ListBox2.Items.Add(fileInFolder.Name)
        Next

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim myfile As String = Dir$("C:\Users\A\Desktop\Project1\Project1\My Project\Responses\Custom\*.*")

    'Check if file exists
    If System.IO.File.Exists(myfile) = True Then
        'Read the file
        Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(myfile)

        'Save file contents to textbox
        RichTextBox1.Text = objReader.ReadToEnd
        objReader.Close()
    Else
        MsgBox("File not found!")
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define "is not working."  Where/how does it fail?

Comment: it never finds a file as in when iclick on one of the files loaded in to listbox 2 it seems to just jump to the MsgBox("File not found!")

Comment: The obvious question would be... When this happens, what is the value of `my file`?  (Hint: Nobody here can debug this for you.  We can't see your computer.)  What does `Dir$` do?  The path you give it specifies a pattern of files, not a single file, so I'm not sure how you expect it to find a particular file.

Answer (score 0):

Your Listbox2 sub should look like this:

```
Private Sub ListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim myfile As String = "C:\Users\A\Desktop\Project1\Project1\My Project\Responses\Custom\" & ListBox2.SelectedItem

    'Check if file exists
    If System.IO.File.Exists(myfile) = True Then
        'Read the file
        Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(myfile)

        'Save file contents to textbox
        RichTextBox1.Text = objReader.ReadToEnd
        objReader.Close()
    Else
        MsgBox("File not found!")
    End If
End Sub
```

More specifically, your `myfile` should be made up of the path and the listbox selected item, i.e. the file name.

So:

[image]

Comment: omg yes thank you can't believe it was so simple looked everywhere and didn't even think of trying that it works perfect thank you.